# Import firebaseui with rollup

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebaseui, es6-modules, rollupjs

I am trying to import the [firebaseui](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) library with rollup. The ui loads fine if I include firbaseui with the cdn they provide:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
```

but if I instead try to import it with `import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'` I get the following error in the browser: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebaseui". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I am using rollup's plugin-node-resolve and plugin-commonjs with this config:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

export default {
  // If using any exports from a symlinked project, uncomment the following:
  // preserveSymlinks: true,
  input: ["src/index.js"],
  output: {
    file: "public/index.js",
    format: "es",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [resolve(), commonjs()],
};
```

which I thought was meant to handle bare module errors like this, so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: is this on the browser?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes

Comment: If u are using cdn why import it

Comment: I am not using cdn, I just used it to check it was working without the import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this problem is caused by the way firebaseui improperly imports firebase in it's ES module build. I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/722) but it got closed. A workaround is to go into `node_modules` and find the ES module build for firebaseui (`node_modules/firebaseui/dist/esm.js`), and change the first line from `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` to `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`.